# Data from a single column of a sql view not displayed

Tags: php, sql, phpmyadmin, jquery-jtable

I have a `SQL view` in `phpmyadmin` which has a is used to populate data in a table created using `jquery jtable`. The issue is quite bizarre as only one column's data which is being pulled by the view isn't being displayed and all of the others are being displayed without an issue. There is also no issue when I edit the fields and I can see the changes I made in phpmyadmin. How do I get the Successful column to display ? All help is greatly appreciated.

Screenshot of the table

[image]

`js` which handles creation of the table

```
function getLessonsLearnedResponseChildTable(ContainerID) {
var table = {
    title: '',
    width: '5%',
    sorting: false,
    edit: false,
    create: false,
    display: function(data) {
        //create an image to be used to open child table
        var $img = $('<img src="' + config.base_url + 'assets/images/expand_row-small.png" title="View Responses" style="height:30px;width:30px;cursor:pointer;" height="30" width="30"/>');
        $img.click(function() {
            $('#' + ContainerID).jtable('openChildTable',
                    $img.closest('tr'),
                    {
                        title: data.record.event,// + ' - Response Plans'
                        actions: {
                            listAction: config.base_url + "data_fetch/responses/" + data.record.risk_id,
                            deleteAction: config.base_url + 'data_fetch/delete_response/',
                            updateAction: config.base_url + 'data_fetch/edit_response/'
                        },
                        messages: defaultResponseMessages,
                        fields: LessonsLearnedResponseFields
                    }, function(data) {//opened handler
                data.childTable.jtable('load');
            });
        });
        //return image to show on row
        return $img;
    }
};
return table;
}
```

Controller method for the listAction:

```
function responses($risk_id = null, $offset = 0, $limit = 100, $order_by = 'response_id', $direction = 'ASC') {
    $confirm_member = $this->User_model->confirm_member(true, false);
    if (!$confirm_member['success']) {
        $this->print_jtable_error(self::ERROR_NOT_LOGGED_IN);
        return;
    }
    $user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
    $this->load->model('Response_model');
    $responses = $this->Response_model->get_all($risk_id, $user_id, $limit, $offset, $order_by, $direction);
    if ($responses == false) {
        $this->print_jtable_error(self::ERROR_NO_ACCESS_PERMISSION);
        return;
    } else {
        return $this->print_jtable_result($responses);
    }
}
```

`get_all` method in `Response Model`

```
/*
 * Retrieves all responses associated with the risk
 */

public function get_all($risk_id, $user_id, $limit = null, $offset = 0, $order_by = null, $direction = 'ASC') {
    //load risk model to check if user can read from project
    $this->load->model('Risk_model');
    if ($this->Risk_model->initialize($risk_id, $user_id) == false) {
        return false;
    }
    if ($limit !== null && $limit != 0) {
        $this->db->limit($limit, $offset);
    }
    if ($order_by !== null) {
        $this->db->order_by($order_by, $direction);
    }
    $query = $this->db->select('SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS *', false)->from('view_responses')->where('risk_id', $risk_id)->get();
    $data = $query->result_array();
    $this->load->model('Task_model');
    foreach ($data as &$response)
        $response['WBS'] = $this->Task_model->normalize_WBS($response['WBS']);
    $data['num_rows'] = $this->db->
                    query('SELECT FOUND_ROWS()', false)->row(0)->{'FOUND_ROWS()'};
    return $data;
}
```

Screenshot of the `sql view`

[image]

`successful` is received but not displayed

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hyUYZ.jpg

Comment: Could you please post the definition of the view and some sample data that should render the output you're not getting?

Comment: No code, no help. A picture of the problem is useless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been able to solve the problem. It was an issue with spelling. I had a missing c in successful coming from the SQL view and now its working fine.